# Outlook 365 works fine with mobil hotspot but when logged into home wifi network doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows-10-desktop, outlook-2016

The outlook 365 in windows 10 behaving strangely. one day suddenly it stopped working and I no longer could synchronize my emails. (Probably due to an update).

When windows is connected to my mobile hotspot the outlook works fine but as soon as I connect back to a home wifi network it stops synchronizing emails. I suspect that it is problem with the wifi router but all other devices such as phones and tablets are connected to wifi and emails and other functions work fine. I tried with another email client (Thunderbird) but the problem persists.
Last night I had a three hours session with Microsoft support but all we could conclude was above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Finally, I found a solution. I did everything except uninstalling and reinstall office 365. I reinstall Office 365 and outlook works fine now.